# Convert string to int in VBA SQL query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to import a dbf table (FoxPro) into a temporary MS Access table and copy 2 coloumns into a final one before deleting the temp one.

My code looks like this

```
'read all data into temp table
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", DSNCONNECTIONSTRING, acTable, "BEL_PLZ", "Belegungsplaetze_Temp", False
'update table
With CurrentDb
    .Execute "INSERT INTO Belegungsplaetze (Belegungsplatznr,Bezeichnung) " & _
            "SELECT NR,BEZ FROM Belegungsplaetze_Temp t " & _
            "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Belegungsplaetze s " & _
            "WHERE t.NR = s.Belegungsplatznr) "
     .Execute "UPDATE Belegungsplaetze SET Belegungsplatznr = Trim([Belegungsplatznr]);"
End With
```

The problem I'm facing is that the field "NR" from "Belegungsplaetze_Temp" is a string and I would like to have it as an integer in my final table (final table has 2 coloumns Belegungsplatznr = Int and Bezeichnung = short text)

Comment: `Val(NR)` https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-val-function-to-convert-text-values-to-numbers-05dce9ac-1687-4eed-bc81-cc46db2767a5 alternatively can convert to a specific numeric type using one of the functions on this page: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-conversion-functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202

Comment: @serakfalcon I would say that your comment is a valid perfect answer to post and close this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer's credit belongs entirely to [serakfalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3138531/serakfalcon), as they provide a completely valid anwser in the comments of the question.

Use the `Val(NR)` function to convert Text values into numbers. [Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-val-function-to-convert-text-values-to-numbers-05dce9ac-1687-4eed-bc81-cc46db2767a5). And some [Type Conversion Functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-conversion-functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202).